# How can I generate an random string with exactly length in PHP?

Tags: php, random, uuid

I have a command to generate an random string as :

`$random = sprintf('%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535))`

But when I test it, sometime they return the string with 10, 11 or 12 length. Anyone can fix this command to always return exactly a string with 12 length (not 10 or 11, etc...). Because of my project, I only can use this command, so please help me fix it and without use a new solution. Thanks all and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Do you use `$random` in numeric context? Because the string returned is always 12 chars long, but maybe you lose leading zeroes if you use it as a (hex) number.

Comment: Upon reexamining the original code, I realised it is as what @syck said, it is actually returning string of length 12. Can the original poster please elaborate a little more on what is actually wrong with the output (or rather is there anything wrong with the output)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$random = sprintf('%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));
$random = str_pad($random, 12, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $random;
```

This will pad the variable $random with 0 until it has length of 12.